# Getting audio data from m3u8 stream to send to captioning in client side browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, getusermedia

Sorry this question has vague code. The question is more about if what I'm thinking is doable or not.

I am trying to find out if it's possible to get the stream audio data from a m3u8 stream that has aac, decode it to raw audio, and then send it to an api that processes the audio.

Their example code has a browser example, which gets mic input using .getUserMedia and then processes the audio and sends it through a websocket.

What I want to know is if it's possible to somehow open a m3u8 stream (like with something like hls.js), decode aac audio,  and then instead of the mic input, patch the raw audio instead of mic input.

### Below is the code:

```
function onOpen(event) {
    resetDisplay();
    statusElement.innerHTML = "Opened";
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(micStream => {
        audioContext.suspend();
        var scriptNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(4096, 1, 1);
        var input = (input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(micStream));
        scriptNode.addEventListener("audioprocess", event =>
            processAudioEvent(event)
        );
        input.connect(scriptNode);
        scriptNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
        audioContext.resume();
    });
}

function processAudioEvent(e) {
    if (
        audioContext.state === "suspended" ||
        audioContext.state === "closed" ||
        !websocket
    ) {
        return;
    }

    let inputData = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);

    // The samples are floats in range [-1, 1]. Convert to PCM16le.
    let output = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(inputData.length * 2));
    for (let i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
        let multiplier = inputData[i] < 0 ? 0x8000 : 0x7fff; // 16-bit signed range is -32768 to 32767
        output.setInt16(i * 2, (inputData[i] * multiplier) | 0, true); // index, value, little edian
    }

    let intData = new Int16Array(output.buffer);
    let index = intData.length;
    while (index-- && intData[index] === 0 && index > 0) { }
    websocket.send(intData.slice(0, index + 1));
}
```

### Side question:

While researching on this I found out that `.createScriptProcessor` is deprecated saying:

> Note: As of the August 29 2014 Web Audio API spec publication, this feature has been marked as deprecated, and was replaced by AudioWorklet (see AudioWorkletNode).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createScriptProcessor

Does anybody know how to rewrite the code above so it uses AudioWorklet or does it require a complete rewrite.

I hope my questions demonstrate my level of ignorance on this subject.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't put more than one question here; instead ask a new one.

Comment: Didn't know that, sorry. Will create a new question.